# Instantiating .NET Print Server

Tags: c#, .net, printing

**Final Edit** 
Apparently I've been barking up the wrong tree.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

> “Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.”

**Edit**
I haven't been able to get the .NET print server code to work.  We have a collection of web services that perform small steps in a workflow, one of them is to print PDFs.  I need to be able to send requests to a print server via .NET without having the print drivers installed the web server hosting the web services.  Is there even a way to do this?  If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

**Original ?**

I'm trying to connect to a remote print server in a different domain with the following code.

```
ps = new PrintServer(@"\\scanprn01",PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter);
```

Every time I do so though, it throws the following Access Denied error.  I've verified the account I'm using (via System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name) and that account is an administrator on the print server and has explicit full permissions to all the printers.  Any advice?

*Access Denied Error*

> System.Printing.PrintServerException was unhandled
>    HResult=-2147024891
>    Message=An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: Access is denied.
>
> Source=System.Printing
>    StackTrace:
>         at System.Printing.PrintServer.Initialize(String path, String[] propertiesFilter, PrinterDefaults printerDefaults)
>         at System.Printing.PrintServer..ctor(String path, PrintSystemDesiredAccess desiredAccess)
>          at StubBP2Tester.frmBP2Tester.btnConnectPQ_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\vsworkspace\StubBP2Tester\StubBP2Tester\Form1.cs:line 36

Comment: The exception leaves nothing whatsoever to the imagination, the account in fact does not have permission to use the server.  Ask IT staff or whomever is responsible for that server to help you out.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure that this is correct. I can reproduce the problem even with `LocalPrintServer` and running as admin with admin-privileges. Interestingly, `PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer` and `PrintSystemDesiredAccess.EnumerateServer` work fine, only `...UsePrinter` and `...AdministratePrinter` lead to this exception.

Comment: I really don't think this is a access rights problem. I worked with `System.Printing` and always had the feeling that these classes are buggy. All Windows API `OpenPrinter()` etc. calls work fine in the same user accounts where `System.Printing.PrintServer`  throws. The constructor even throws when you don't specify the properties you want (so it tries to take all), but the spooler has no default queue. Plus in that case the method that builds the exception message _throws itself_. So you don't event get a usefull error message.

Comment: I don't think it's an access rights issue, as I mentioned in the original post I have every right you could possibly get on the boxes in question other than domain admin privileges.